# Java Mockito - How Mock private member that initializing in the constructor

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I tried to mock a member that has `collect` function to return a Mock object instead of getting to the function itself.
But, It getting into the function no matter how i tried to mock the private member.

```
public class BasicReportManager implements ReportManager {
    private final ReportCollector reportCollector;

    public BasicReportManager(String id) {
        this.reportCollector = new ReportCollector(id);
    }

    private void processReport(ReportType reportTypeToProcess) {
        switch (reportTypeToProcess) {
            case REPORT1:
                Sendable collect = reportCollector.collect();
        }
    }
}
```

The Test code -

```
ReportCollector reportData = Mockito.mock(ReportCollector.class);
Sendable sendable = Mockito.mock(Sendable.class);
Mockito.when(reportData.collect()).thenReturn(sendable);
```

But, When I call the `processReport()` the collect function occurs.
How can I fix it?

BasicReportManager Test Building -

```
basicReportManager = new BasicReportManager("1");
```

Thank you.

Comment: We need to see (a) how your test creates an instance of `BasicReportManager` and (b) the implementation of `reportCollector()` within `BasicReportManager`.

Comment: I just edit the question with the created instance of BasicReportManager on the Test and Fix the copy-paste problem with the reportCollector(). I should be the reportCollector member. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to mock the instance of `ReportCollector` which is used by `BasicReportManager` then you must inject it when your test case creates `BasicReportManager`. For example:

```
ReportCollector reportData = Mockito.mock(ReportCollector.class);
Sendable sendable = Mockito.mock(Sendable.class);
Mockito.when(reportData.collect()).thenReturn(sendable);

BasicReportManager basicReportManager = new BasicReportManager("1", reportData);

// now your test invocation on BasicReportManager will use the mocked instance of ReportCollector
```

You could consider al alternative like providing a factory for `ReportCollector` but this simple fact remains: in order to let `BasicReportManager` use  a mocked instance of `ReportCollector` in your test case you have to be able (somehow!) to provide `BasicReportManager` with that mocked instance.

Answer (score 1):

You are mocking a `ReportCollector` object but you never use it inside `BasicReportManager`.
You should change the `BasicReportManager` constructor:

```
public BasicReportManager(ReportCollector reportCollector) {
    this.reportCollector = reportCollector;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
ReportCollector reportData = Mockito.mock(ReportCollector.class);
Sendable sendable = Mockito.mock(Sendable.class);
Mockito.when(reportData.collect()).thenReturn(sendable);

basicReportManager = new BasicReportManager(reportData);
```